# create a searchable database of word documents

Tags: database, html, twitter-bootstrap, database-design, ms-word

At work we have a large amout of processes which are laid out in several different Word documents.  Some as large as 30mb and they include screenshots.  What I would like to do is create a front end using in order to be able to search all of them simultaneously and have autocomplete to suggest which part of the process to go to.  I've looked at various ways of doing this but it seems I would have to put all the Word document data in to a database to make it work and that would have the disadvantage of not being able to see the screenshots.  Is the best way to compile all of the processes in to one Word document then search that somehow or would I need to export the different sections in to a database but how would I then make the screenshots visible?  The other way I was thinking was making each part of the processes in to a seperate page which I could call via bootstrap as I have a rough idea of how to structure the data.  The problem is this would be very laborious and I'd prefer if there was a way of categorising it by some automated process or script.  Any ideas welcome. The method I would like to implement is a single web page which I could store locally and everyone could access implemented using Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be off topic, based on the subject...

but at first glance, A simple media-heavy Filemaker database could be made in 30 minutes, and you could implement .pdfs of the Word files as well as full text content, for quick lookups.

The added advantage would be that you could access it via iOS, Mac, or PC....

This option could easily allow thumbnails as well as full documents (.doc or .pdf) either inserted or attached to the file, and available for download if preferred..

The only component of prep which could take time would be actually cutting .pdfs from each Word file to attach for easy viewing...

You would then reference the text in each file in one record field, view the thumbnails in another, and download (or read) the whole document in another. Filemaker allows numerous views of any record, and this can all be accomplished quickly in a single layout.

Comment: That looks interesting but I wanted a solution that didn't involve the company spending money if possible.

Comment: the only 'solutions' not involving money are going to cost a good bit of time..  and if you're not a non-profit (or willing to donate your time for free), that's going to cost money as well.....  Another solution is to have one made quite cheap/quick on upwork (https://www.upwork.com/Login?redir=%2F) - shouldn' be more than a few minutes of time by a rather inexpensive database guy, and the FileMaker pro app can be output in a stand-alone app which means you never have to buy the software.....

Comment: Cheers.  I'll look in to the app if it can do that sounds ideal.